# Dynamic Worksheet search

Tags: excel, vba

I have created some coding which is designed to open up a file from a designated filepath, search for a worksheet and copy the desired information from the worksheets I am looking for and paste into the original document which the coding is assigned to. The worksheet I need to copy from is named MMM YY. When I originally set the coding up, I would manually update monthly, however, I am passing the document onto someone else to use, so would like the search reference to be dynamic. I’ve created the below coding where ‘DRT’ is the dynamic reference, where `DRT = Today()` formatted in the MMM YY style.

Many Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Y As Workbook
Dim X As Workbook
Dim Filepath As String
Dim DRT As String

Filepath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calc").Range("Filepathdan").Value
DRT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calc").Range("DR").Value

Set Y = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set X = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Filepath)

For Each ws In X.Sheets
    If InStr(1, ws.Name, DRT) Then
        Cells.Copy
        Y.Activate
        Worksheets("Dan").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        Worksheets("Dan").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws
X.Close False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to copy the worksheet with `Cells.Copy`, you are missing the reference of the worksheet, just add `ws` in the begining, so use `ws.Cells.Copy`.

Also, there's no need to `Activate` the `Y` workbook with `Y.Activate`, you should fully qualify the Pasted range, by using `Y.Worksheets("Dan").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Y As Workbook
Dim X As Workbook
Dim Filepath As String
Dim DRT As String

Filepath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calc").Range("Filepathdan").Value
'DRT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calc").Range("DR").Value
' ======= EDITED LINE ======
DRT = Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calc").Range("DR").Value, "MMM YYYY")

Set Y = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set X = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Filepath)

For Each ws In X.Sheets
    '=== for DEBUG ONLY ===
    Debug.Print DRT & " | Worksheet name is: " & ws.Name

    If InStr(1, ws.Name, DRT) > 0 Then
        ws.Cells.Copy
        Y.Worksheets("Dan").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Y.Worksheets("Dan").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws
X.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai, Thanks for the quick response, however the code above still doesn't perform. It opens the desired workbook and loops through the tabs however it doesn't find the correlating tab. I believe it is down to the "DRT"  in the If InStr(1, ws.Name, DRT) > 0 Then, as if I replace DRT with "Jun 2017" then the coding performs correctly. Once again, many thanks

Comment: @Matt555 see my edited code, run it, and let me know what you got in your immediate window

Comment: 13/06/2017 | Worksheet name is: Jan 2017
13/06/2017 | Worksheet name is: Feb 2017
13/06/2017 | Worksheet name is: Mar 2017
13/06/2017 | Worksheet name is: Apr 2017
13/06/2017 | Worksheet name is: May 2017
13/06/2017 | Worksheet name is: Jun 2017; This is what returns. The "DRT" value is JUN 2017 so should return the values but it returns blank cells. cheers

Comment: @Matt555 your dates format don't match, `13/06/2017` doesn't equal to `Jun 2017` as `InStr` function concerns. You need to change the format of the date, do you know how ?

Comment: Would it be something like this?       thanks!                                                                                                    DRT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calc").Range("DR").Value
 DRT = Format(Date, "MMM YY")

Comment: No it still doesn't like it.

Comment: Great! this is the one! Thanks for the response and patience!